# QuantLib C++: Monte Carlo Engine with SequenceStatistics

Tags: programming, monte-carlo, quantlib

I'm trying to implement a Monte Carlo PricingEngine that stores multidimensional statistics.

I have done the following:

1. Defined a Monte Carlo Trait that among other things stores as the **path_pricer_type** `PathPricer<MultiPath,Array>` (my process is one dimensional but has 2 factors). let's call this struct **MyMCTrait**.
2. Implemented a class that derives from both `McSimulation<MyMCTrait,PseudoRandom,SequenceStatistics>` and `VanillaOption::engine`.
3. Implemented a `PathPricer<MultiPath,Array>` in which the first element of the Array returned by the operator() is the price of the option.

I'm getting compiling errors because in methods value() and valueWithSamples() of class McSimulation we have the following initializations:

a. `result_type(mcModel_->sampleAccumulator().mean());`

b. `result_type error(mcModel_->sampleAccumulator().errorEstimate());`

that are trying to cast from `std::vector<Real>` (returned by the SequenceStatistics methods) to Array (result_type).

I doubt that the right way to go is to implement the cast (if it's possible), could anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

### EDIT

I got the Pricing Engine working by using a derived class from `SequenceStatistics`. I just overrode the inspectors mean() and errorEstimate() and made them return an Array. To do this I used the base class methods + the Array constructor that takes begin and end iterators.

**I'm still wondering though if this is the right way to proceed. Thanks for any thoughts.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct, given the implementation of `McSimulation` and the interface of `SequenceStatistics`. We should probably have defined `SequenceStatistics` as returning instances of `Array`...

As you might have seen, trying to return `std::vector<Real>` from the path pricer wouldn't work; the result type needs to define arithmetic operations such as addition and subtraction.